# Haskell method with two where clauses

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I want to write a Haskell function which has two where clauses but I get this error from the compiler:

> Syntax error in input (unexpected symbol "changeNew")

```
changeItem oPos nPos (x:xs) 
                        | oPos < nPos = changeOld
                        | oPos > nPos = changeNew
                        | otherwise = x : changeItem (oPos-1) (nPos-1) xs
                        where changeOld
                            | oPos == 0 = (xs !! nPos) : changeItem x (nPos-1) xs
                            | nPos == 0 = oPos : xs
                            | otherwise = x : changeItem (oPos-1) (nPos-1) xs
                        changeNew
                            | oPos == 0 = nPos : xs
                            | nPos == 0 = (xs !! oPos) : changeItem (oPos-1) x xs
                            | otherwise = x : changeItem (oPos-1) (nPos-1) xs
```

What is wrong with the code? Why can't I declare two where clauses?

Comment: Try converting your tabs to spaces in your code (your editor should have support for this if it's a decent editor).  Tabs in Haskell often lead to problems like this.  You have to have `changeNew` line up with `changeOld`, which is a lot easier with spaces.

Comment: Others have given you the answer. I thought I'd give you a suggestion: don't indent the guards for changeItem so far. The code is falling off the edge of the world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The names being defined in the `where` clause need to line up on the left-hand side, like this

```
changeItem oPos nPos (x:xs) 
                        | oPos < nPos = changeOld
                        | oPos > nPos = changeNew
                        | otherwise = x : changeItem (oPos-1) (nPos-1) xs
                        where 
                          changeOld
                            | oPos == 0 = (xs !! nPos) : changeItem x (nPos-1) xs
                            | nPos == 0 = oPos : xs
                            | otherwise = x : changeItem (oPos-1) (nPos-1) xs
                          changeNew
                            | oPos == 0 = nPos : xs
                            | nPos == 0 = (xs !! oPos) : changeItem (oPos-1) x xs
                            | otherwise = x : changeItem (oPos-1) (nPos-1) xs
```

Although a more "usual" Haskell style would move everything to the left, to prevent your code marching off into the bottom right hand corner.

```
changeItem oPos nPos (x:xs) 
  | oPos < nPos = changeOld
  | oPos > nPos = changeNew
  | otherwise = x : changeItem (oPos-1) (nPos-1) xs
 where 
  changeOld
    | oPos == 0 = (xs !! nPos) : changeItem x (nPos-1) xs
    | nPos == 0 = oPos : xs
    | otherwise = x : changeItem (oPos-1) (nPos-1) xs
  changeNew
    | oPos == 0 = nPos : xs
    | nPos == 0 = (xs !! oPos) : changeItem (oPos-1) x xs
    | otherwise = x : changeItem (oPos-1) (nPos-1) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong. `changeNew` needs to line up with `changeOld` rather than with `where`.